# How to solve the composite function using graph

Tags: functions

How to solve the composite function using graph ?
 [image]
I know the analytical method to solve the composite function (i.e to find $f \circ g$ or $g \circ f$). Is there any graphical method to find $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$?

Comment: Mention clearly the question by giving an example question, what is given and what is to be found.

Comment: I have give an example see, it plz

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, it can be done graphically in a  convenient way. The composition would be difficult to analyse graphically as compared to usual way you do by substitution. Especially for complicated cases, it would be nearly impossible.  But, sketching a graph for each function definitely provides more clarity while finding composition regarding the domain, etc. Hope this helps you